# Content going out of container when padding has been added

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with content going outside of a container. It is happening in the service_description area of my code. I have padding set vertically and horizontally for the description. The vertical padding is taking place just not the horizontal.

To make the description come out just click in one of the boxes and then you will see what I am referring to. I want all of the content to remain in that box.

Why is this doing this when I have padding set?

```js
$('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));
  $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide().parent().removeClass('closed');
  thisDescription.slideToggle(500).parent().toggleClass('closed');
});
```

```css
.page_wrap {
  margin: 15px 10%
}
.left_service_wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.service_wrapper {
  margin-left: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 80%;
}
.service_list {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.service_title {
  padding: 15px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.service_title:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7i2.png') 0 0 / 10px 10px no-repeat;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
.closed .service_title:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4L4.png');
}
.service_title:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page_wrap">
  <div class="left_service_wrap">
    <div class="service_list">
      <div class="service_wrapper">
        <div class="service_title">Flooring</div>
        <div class="service_description">The best floors! gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
          ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service_wrapper">
        <div class="service_title">Roofing</div>
        <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect! gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
          ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `html, body { box-sizing: border-box; } *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }`

Comment: No, I am not familiar with that css command.

Comment: It takes into account padding and border lengths, by default it is content-box which doesn't take padding and borders into account. put those two rules at the top of your styles.

Comment: @zer00ne the code you entered did not help. It actually took away padding I had between the image of the + sign and the title.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it....Did you want all of that text clipped,  stretching the container, or wrapping inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `word-wrap` to your `.service_description` class which should break the words onto a new line when it reaches the end of the container.

```
.service_description {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  width: 100%; /* Probably should remove this as well */
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: @Becky someone (wasn't saying it was you) down-voted immediately after I posted the answer.

Comment: @sbeliv01 That's why I'm commenting

Answer (score 1):

the "words" are too long i.e. longer than a full line), but in real life you'll never have words that long...

EDIT / addition:

And here:

```
.service_description {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

the 100% width adds up  with 2 x 14 px padding (i.e. real width is 100% plus 28px). Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to that rule to include the padding in the width.

Comment: Putting spaces in did actually help. It recognized the padding then.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
.service_wrapper { overflow:hidden; }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-wrap` and `box-sizing` to your `.service_decription`:

```
.service_description {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: none;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```js
 $('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
      var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));
      $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide().parent().removeClass('closed');
      thisDescription.slideToggle(500).parent().toggleClass('closed');
    });
```

```css
    .page_wrap {
      margin: 15px 10%
    }
    .left_service_wrap {
      float: left;
      width: 40%;
      margin-left: 5%;
    }
    .service_wrapper {
      margin-left: 25%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 15px 0;
      width: 80%;
    }
    .service_list {
      margin-left: 20%;
    }
    .service_title {
      padding: 15px 12px;
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    .service_title:before {
      content: '';
      background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7i2.png') 0 0 / 10px 10px no-repeat;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-right: 6px;
    }
    .closed .service_title:before {
      background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4L4.png');
    }
    .service_title:hover {
      background-color: gray;
      color: blue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .service_description {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: none;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page_wrap">
      <div class="left_service_wrap">
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="service_wrapper">
            <div class="service_title">Flooring</div>
            <div class="service_description">The best floors! gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
              ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="service_wrapper">
            <div class="service_title">Roofing</div>
            <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect! gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
              ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggg gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```